# Convert greyscale to Rgb

Tags: c++, bitmap, rgb, grayscale

[Here is my full code code](https://pastebin.com/YNBF44Xu) - An extract of the code is at the bottom of the question.

I have problem with function `policz` and `koloruj`. I need to convert the bitmap in greyscale to rgb.

There is a table showing how the bitmap should be converted from `n(greyscale)`to  `rgb(color)`. Running the below code snippet shows how the bitmap should be converted:

```html
<table align="center"><tr><b><th align="center">n</th><th align="center">r<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">g<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">b<sub>n</sub></th></b></tr><tr><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr><tr><td align="center">1-85</td><td align="center">r<sub>n-1</sub>+3</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr><tr><td align="center">86</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr><tr><td align="center">87-170</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">g<sub>n-1</sub>+3</td><td align="center">0</td></tr><tr><td align="center">171</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">0</td></tr><tr><td align="center">172-255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">b<sub>n-1</sub>+3</td></tr></table>
```

The picture which i need to convert:
[image]

```
int policz(int i, char rgb, kolor tab[])
{
    int p;
    switch (rgb)
    {
    case 'r':
        p = tab[i-1].R+3;
        if(p>255)
        {
            return 255;
        }
        else return p;
        break;
    case 'g':
        p= tab[i-1].G+3;
        if(p>255)
        {
            return 255;
        }
        else return p;
        break;
    case 'b':
        p= tab[i-1].B+3;;
        if(p>255)
        {
            return 255;
        }
        else return p;
        break;
    }
}
void koloruj(unsigned char tab[], kolor tab_k[], BITMAPINFOHEADER ob)
{
    char rgb;
    for(int i=0; i<ob.biSizeImage/3; i++)
    {



        if(tab[i]==0)
        {
            tab_k[i].R=0;
            tab_k[i].G=0;
            tab_k[i].B=0;

        }
        NULL;
        if(tab[i]>0 && tab[i]<86)
        {
            rgb = 'r';
            tab_k[i].R=policz(i, rgb,tab_k);
            tab_k[i].G=0;
            tab_k[i].B=0;
        }
        NULL;
        if(tab[i]==86)
        {
            tab_k[i].R=255;
            tab_k[i].G=0;
            tab_k[i].B=0;
        }
        NULL;
        if(tab[i]>86 && tab[i]<171)
        {
            rgb = 'b';
            tab_k[i].R=255;
            tab_k[i].G=policz(i, rgb,tab_k);
            tab_k[i].B=0;
        }
        NULL;
        if(tab[i]==171)
        {
            tab_k[i].R=255;
            tab_k[i].G=255;
            tab_k[i].B=0;
        }
        NULL;
        if(tab[i]>171 && tab[i]<256)
        {
            rgb = 'b';
            tab_k[i].R=255;
            tab_k[i].G=255;
            tab_k[i].B=policz(i, rgb, tab_k);
        }
        NULL;
    }
}
```

Code i guess in 1function of both i have mistake which make me nervous

Comment: So you have a picture which only contains grey-scale information. You want to add color information. Where would that additional information come from? Are you sure that you the goal is not converting from color to grey? That would be possible.

Comment: Also, please provide all needed information here, instead of linking externally.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8KPd.png there is this table

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkB6J.png and there is the picture whom i need to convert from greyscale to rgb

Comment: and im sure that my task is conver the greyscale to rgb

Comment: Please provide all helpful information directly here, not by linking. Provide textutal information as text directly here, not by linking to a picture.

Comment: If your task is to convert from grey to color, where should the additional information come from? Or do you want to convert from greyscale to greys, expressed as identical RGB values?

Comment: Please add information by [edit]ing the question, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: i guess the 2nd one

Comment: i not ignored i add links to imgur

Comment: because i dont know how i can show te picture on forum it is my first time here

Comment: If you work on all my comments, then I will make your picture visible for you, but only the one which is not of text.

Comment: If you have code, then please show it as [mre] here and explain what is missing or misbehaving. Ideally translate everything to English, that will improve your chances.

Comment: `NULL;` does nothing... Did you copy this from somewhere?

Comment: @Suv Do you have a link to the original `.bmp` file, not a `.png`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your program is leaking memory. Try to stay away from using `new`. Use smart pointers instead. This is a snippet from your `main()` rewritten to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> pixmap =
    std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(PictureInfo.biSizeImage / 3);

std::unique_ptr<kolor[]> kolormap =
    std::make_unique<kolor[]>(PictureInfo.biSizeImage / 3);

odczytaj_obraz(obraz, pixmap.get(), PictureInfo);
koloruj(pixmap.get(), kolormap.get(), PictureInfo);
```

---

Second, your definitions of [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapfileheader) and [BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader) are incorrect. Copied and converted, they should look like this:

```
using WORD = uint16_t;
using DWORD = uint32_t;
using LONG = int32_t;

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER {
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
};
```

---

When it comes to the actual conversion, if I'm reading the table correctly, it could be simplified to this:

```html
<table align="center"><tr><b><th align="center">n</th><th align="center">r<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">g<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">b<sub>n</sub></th></b></tr> <tr><td align="center">0-85</td><td align="center">n*3</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr> <tr><td align="center">86-171</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">(n-86)*3</td><td align="center">0</td></tr> <tr><td align="center">172-255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">(n-171)*3</td></tr></table>
```

In which case, the conversion could be done like this:

```
struct rgb_t {
    uint8_t r, g, b;
};

inline uint8_t scale(uint8_t n, uint8_t cutover) {
    return (n-cutover)*3;
}

rgb_t gray2rgb(uint8_t n) {
    static constexpr uint8_t cutover_rg = 86;
    static constexpr uint8_t cutover_gb = 171;

    if(n < cutover_rg) return {scale(n, 0), 0, 0};
    if(n <= cutover_gb) return {255, scale(n, cutover_rg), 0};
    return {255, 255, scale(n, cutover_gb)};
}
```

[Demo of gray2rgb()](https://godbolt.org/z/syp9ax)

Interesting values:

```
n       r       g       b
---------------------------
0       0       0       0
1       3       0       0

85      255     0       0
86      255     0       0
87      255     3       0

170     255     252     0
171     255     255     0
172     255     255     3

254     255     255     249
255     255     255     252
```

From this output, where n<sub>85</sub> and n<sub>86</sub> gives the same rgb value and where n<sub>255</sub> does not result in b being 255, it feels like the table should be adjusted:

```html
<table align="center"><tr><b><th align="center">n</th><th align="center">r<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">g<sub>n</sub></th><th align="center">b<sub>n</sub></th></b></tr> <tr><td align="center">0-85</td><td align="center">n*3</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr> <tr><td align="center">86-170</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">(n-85)*3</td><td align="center">0</td></tr> <tr><td align="center">171-255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">255</td><td align="center">(n-170)*3</td></tr></table>
```

```
rgb_t gray2rgb_improved(uint8_t n) {
    static constexpr uint8_t cutover_rg = 85;
    static constexpr uint8_t cutover_gb = 170;

    if(n <= cutover_rg) return {scale(n, 0), 0, 0};
    if(n <= cutover_gb) return {255, scale(n, cutover_rg), 0};
    return {255, 255, scale(n, cutover_gb)};
}
```

[Demo of gray2rgb_improved()](https://godbolt.org/z/X9Zxdy)

Now, the values won't match the original table, but fill the whole spectrum equally:

```
n       r       g       b
---------------------------
0       0       0       0
1       3       0       0

84      252     0       0
85      255     0       0
86      255     3       0
87      255     6       0

169     255     252     0
170     255     255     0
171     255     255     3
172     255     255     6

254     255     255     252
255     255     255     255
```

While `gray2rgb()` probably does what your table says, `gray2rgb_improved()` is probably better.